# Prevent HTML outputting to STDOUT - Google App Engine development environment

Tags: php, python-2.7, google-app-engine

Does anybody know how to prevent the GAE local dev environment from outputting HTML to STDOUT console on 500 errors?  I'm using the bundled PHP and Python runtime on Windows, if that's relevant.

I've found that page load is delayed until it has finished outputting X number of the page HTML lines to the console, plus the stack trace is above the HTML, meaning I have to scroll up a screen every time to see the PHP error.

I'd like it to only output the PHP errors (as specified in php.ini) to the console and nothing else, but the only error output switches I can find (--log_level=warning --dev_appserver_log_level=critical) don't appear to provide an option to suppress everything else.

Does anybody know of another dev_appserver.py switch I may be missing, please?  Outputting HTML to the console is workable, but super-frustrating to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/tools/local-devserver-command) or running `dev_appserver.py --help` I have not found a useful option to directly help you do that. But you could try [XDEBUG](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/tools/using-local-server#debugging_locally_with_xdebug).

Other option is deploying the application and playing with logs to only output the useful information. You can use the [Stackdriver Logging advanced filter](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters) to obtain the information you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - however, I've already noted the logging switches I'm using, which aren't working.  I got these from the the page you've provided the URL for.  

I'm using XDEBUG, but that doesn't provide 500  errors - the STDOUT console is where these appear in GAE dev environment.

Stackdriver is for the production environment, so no use in dev.

Comment: I am with Google Cloud Support. I filed a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110084332) to ask to implement the option. You should star it to push for the implementation and get up-dates.

Comment: Thanks.  The information in the feature request was wrong, so I've added a comment to correct his.

Comment: My bad. Even if I understood the problem I provided a really wrong description. Could you check the new version? I have used "specific language" instead of "PHP" to request a feature that can be applied in more cases.